# Find missing value in array using a for loop

Tags: java

So I am trying to make a for loop that searches through an array and returns how many missing values it has found.

Here is my method:

```
    public void questionsMissed() {
            int missedQuestions = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (answers[i] == null){
                    missedQuestions++;
                }
            }
 System.out.println("You have missed " + missedQuestions + " questions.");
        }
```

The error is where the if statement is. I am assuming it is because of the null. How can I go around finding missing values?

ERROR: incomparable types: int and

Comment: Show us the complete code and problem

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ... and the error, please

Comment: Possible errors just by looking at the code - `answers` out of scope, array out of bounds, etc.

Comment: Sorry. Added all of the code and the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to compare a primitive data type, `int`, to `null`. Only reference types can be compared to `null`. Primitive types always have a value - they cannot be `null`, so the compiler tells you that the comparison does not make sense.

There are two ways you can go about fixing this:

- **Switch the type of `answers` to `Integer`** - This would let you check its values for `null`, at the expense of wrapping primitive integers into by-reference wrappers.
- **You can designate an integer value, say, -1, as "missing"** - This would let you keep `int` as the type of `answer[]`'s element, but there would be a special number that must be used everywhere in your program.

Since you are using `char` values for your answers, I would use the second approach, but first I would make `answers` and `correctAnswers` arrays of `char`. There is a convenient "special value" for the unused value - the null character `\0'`:

```
if (answers[i] == '\0') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the help and being specific with each answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two things :-

There is nothing like missing values which you can compare using null. You can compare it to  0 as those defined array members are initialised to 0 (THANKS to dasblinkenlight for correcting me,I was confused with C),but that appears to be a poor decision/choice.

I'd recommend putting -1 for the missing values as is generally done in sentinel condition checking and then compare values like :-

```
public void questionsMissed() {
    int missedQuestions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (answers[i] == -1){
          System.out.println("OOPS,the element here is missing!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, if I use == 0 doesn't that mean it wouldn't return anything or do most arrays have a default value of 0? Thank you.

Comment: @Lewis-SORRY Lewis,edited my answer. In java,array members are always initialised by 0 whatever be the case so consider -1 for sentinel condition!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight-THANKS,corrected. I was confused between C and Java as nowadays I am busy with some C coding!!! THANKS and +! for you. Also, I mentioned your point in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You compare a primitive type `int` to `null`. Primitive types are not objects and always have a value. Thus you can not compare them to `null`.

If you use an `Integer[]` you can mark missed questions by inserting `null` or you can compare them with '\0'.

But since you already use character literals I would use `Character` instead.

When you use a primitive wrapper type your methods will also get much easier. E.g.

```
Character[] answers = new Character[20];

....

public void questionsMissed() {
    int missedQuestions = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(answers), '\0');
    System.out.println("You have missed " + missedQuestions + " questions.");
}
```